# Correcting Image Stacking Order and Column Alignment for Alternate Screen Sizes

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I'm relatively new at this level of complexity – at any rate, creating a webpage on the Squarespace platform which will feature a code block that presents a grid of 12 clickable tiles with Hover response and click through functionality. While Squarespace has built in responsiveness, whatever is in the code block is exempt from that.

So, the problem I'm having is that my nicely centered grid of 12 tiles is only centered when displayed on a fully open browser window. As the browser window diminishes in size and the tiles begin stacking, the grid aligns to the right. I've already put the gallery in a div in order to get the original centering.

Is there a way to force centering regardless of browser size?

To see the behavior in action, change Result window size of jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/terryogara/VQ3hk/

Thank you, and here's the code:

```
<style type="text/css">

.caption-style-1 li{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 5px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;   
}

.caption-style-1 li:hover .caption{
opacity: 1;
}

.caption-style-1 li:active .caption{
opacity: .5;
}

.caption-style-1 img{
float: left;
}

.caption-style-1 .caption{
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
}

.caption-style-1 .blur{
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
height: 180px;
width: 180px;
position: relative;
}

.caption-style-1 .caption-text{
position: absolute;
width: 180px;
height: 180px;
text-align: center;
top:10px;
}

.outer-container {
width: 100%;
min-width: 980px
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
}

.inner-container {
display: inline-block;
}

</style>

<!-- CONTENT -->

<!--  OUTER CONTAINER -->

<div class="outer-container">
<ul class="caption-style-1">

<!--  ROW 1 TOP | IMAGE GALLERY 1 -->
<div class="inner-container">

<!--  IMAGE 1 -->
<div style="float: right;">
<div style="float: right;">
<a href="http://www.example.com">
<li>
<img src="http://murmurhaus.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/ph-180x180.png" height="180" width="180" alt="ALT">
<div class="caption">
    <div class="blur"></div>
<div class="caption-text">
<h1>TEXT HERE</h1>
</div>
</div>
</li></a>
</div>

<!--  IMAGE 2 -->
<div style="float: right;">
<a href="http://www.google.com">
<li>
<img src="http://murmurhaus.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/ph-180x180.png" height="180" width="180" alt="ALT">
<div class="caption">
    <div class="blur"></div>
<div class="caption-text">
<h1>TEXT HERE</h1>
</div>
</div>
</li></a>
</div>
</div>

<!--  IMAGE 3 -->
<div style="float: right;">
<div style="float: right;">
<a href="http://http://stackoverflow.com/">
<li>
<img src="http://murmurhaus.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/ph-180x180.png" height="180" width="180" alt="ALT">
<div class="caption">
    <div class="blur"></div>
<div class="caption-text">
<h1>TEXT HERE</h1>
</div>
</div>
</li></a>
</div>

<!--  IMAGE 4 -->
<div style="float: right;">
<li>
<img src="http://murmurhaus.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/ph-180x180.png" height="180" width="180" alt="ALT">
<div class="caption">
    <div class="blur"></div>
<div class="caption-text">
<h1>TEXT HERE</h1>
</div>
</div>
</li></a>
</div>
</div>
<!--  END GALLERY 1-->
<!--  CLOSE INNER CONTAINER -->
</div>
  <!--  CLOSE OUTER CONTAINER -->
</ul>
</div>
<!--  END ROW 1 -->
```

Comment: Not sure, but are you looking for Media Queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries ?

Comment: Okay, so I resolved the first issue by nesting each pair of images around another set of divs. The remaining issue eludes me, however: the row of four is nicely centered when the browser window is fully open, but as soon as a I diminish the size, the tiles align right. drip, I'll see if I can find an answer at the media queries page, thank you.